# ExtJS 4 store and manage record

Tags: json, extjs4, store

I have a question about extjs 4.
Below is my storeMsg

```
   var storeMsg = this.getMessageStore();
            storeMsg.load({
                    scope: this,
                    autoLoad: true,
                    params:{
                        read_conditions: Ext.JSON.encode({
                            "employee_rid": '7976', 
                            "year" : '2013',  //etos
                            "kind_holiday_rid" : '1',
                            "request_days" : '5'
                        })
                    },
                    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                            // do something after the load finishes
                            console.log(records[0].get('remain'));
                            console.log(records[0].get('messages'));

                    }
            });
```

and i take a json response like as

```
{"total":1,"success":true,"data":[{"status":"true","messages":"\u03a3\u03c9\u03c3\u03c4\u03cc \u03b1\u03af\u03c4\u03b7\u03bc\u03b1 \u03ac\u03b4\u03b5\u03b9\u03b1\u03c2","remain":"25"}]}
```

I want to take the field status from  json (ex true) outside from  storeMsg.load();
For example

```
var vstatus = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup(storeMsg).data.items[0].data.status
```

but i take message this vstatus is **undefined**

I have changed my variable (vstatus) of code : 
**var vstatus = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup(storeMsg).getProxy().getReader();**
and I am taking and object like as
**className "Ext.data.reader.Json"**
and it has some attributes. An attribute is

```
 jsonData 
    data
      remain     25
      status     true
      message    "Is correct"
    total          1
    success       true
```

and I give in 
       **var vstatus = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup(storeMsg).getProxy().getReader().jsonData;**
and I take this message (**undefined**). 
Do you have any idea how take the value from jsonData.data.status = true;
tnx

and the fully code about store , proxy and reader is below

```
    Ext.define('MHR.store.Message',{
       extend       : 'Ext.data.Store',
           model        : 'MHR.model.Message',
           storeId      : 'Message',
           autoLoad         : true,
       proxy        : {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
        read    : 'php/crud.php?action=check'

    },
    actionMethods: {
       read    : 'POST',
            },
    reader: {
                type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        rootProperty: 'data',
        successProperty: 'success',
        messageProperty: 'message'
    },
            extraParams : {
               'read_conditions': ''

           }
   }
 });
```

Comment: Could you post your full store/proxy/reader config? It would help determine if the issue is with your store or the way you're accessing the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
storeMsg.each(function(record) {
    var status = record.get('status');
});
```